# ASP Core: How to set httpContext.User?

Tags: asp.net, identity, httpcontext

I writing middleware for authentication with tokens. *(don't ask me: "why?")*.

```
...
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
private RequestDelegate next;
private WareHouseDbContext context; 
...
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var header = httpContext.Request.Headers.Where(x => x.Key == "Authorization");
    if (header.Count() == 1)
    {
        var token = header.First().Value.First();
        if (token.Contains("Bearer"))
        {
            var name = TokenEncryptor.Decrypt(token.Replace("Bearer ", ""));
            var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == name);

            if (user != null)
            {
                httpContext.User = user; // ???? how do this  ???/
            }
        }
    }           
    await next.Invoke(httpContext);
}
```

Please answer me how to set httpContext.User?

Comment: name found is correct.

Comment: please. help me

Answer (score 13):

you must create `IPrincipal` object like this

```
var user = new GenericPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(userData.Username), userData.Roles);
httpContext.User = user;
```