# Use React Authentication with .NET backend?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-7.0

We have a project using a React frontend with a .NET Core backend. We're in the process of implementing Ping One for authentication. We have a working version of the auth, using the SDK located [here](https://github.com/pingidentity-developers-experience/ping-oidc-client-sdk).

Now we need to have that user also be authenticated on the .NET Core side. Specifically, we need to get an `IPrincipal` from `HttpContext`, which I expect would be a `ClaimsPrincipal` with appropriate information set, and even more specifically, the `IPrincipal.Identity.Name` field mapped to the authenticating claims identity identifier and the `IPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated` field set to true.

I am, however, at an absolute loss as to how to make this happen. The authentication context does provide an `access_token` and an `id_token`. Is there some way to call something within `IPrincipal` to set the authentication session state by passing an `access_token` or `id_token`? I do see from research that there does seem to be some concept using `JwtBearerToken` - such as for example, [this tutorial](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3669188/how-to-implement-jwt-authentication-in-aspnet-core.html). Is that the right approach to be following? And, if it is, how would we pass that information from the client to the server?

As another approach, I saw [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44625464/1289046](https://this%20response) here on SO, as a potential way of setting the `IPrincipal` directly. Could this approach work? And if so, are there any potential drawbacks I need to be aware of?

Please let me know if there's any other info I can provide, as this is an area I'm not hugely familiar with - in the past we've used pure server-side authentication by simply calling `Authorize`, which does all the work for us.

Comment: It is common for a "JS + .NET" setup to make .NET responsible for the login and for managing users (+ roles, if applicable). It may feel like starting over, but I would recommend investigating if it is possible for .NET to authenticate against Ping One (of which I know nothing, by the way). After the login, .NET knows who they are and generates a JWT Token and passes that to the JS Frontend which it can (and must) then use every time it makes an API call to .NET.